# Django not show image field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Not showing image on upload, what is the problem?

**setting.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

**html.**

```
    {% for tt in article %}
<div class="content_box">
    <div class="content_l left">
        <div class="horoscope_box_big">
            <div class="blog_img1">
                <img src="{{ tt.image.url }}" alt="{{tt.title}}" width="50%" /> {{ tt.image.url }}
            </div>
            <h1 class="blog_title1"> {{ tt.Title }}
<div class="blog_descr1"><h1>more about</h1>

<p> {{ tt.body }}</p>

</div>
        </div>
    
    
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Blogmodel(models.Model):
    Title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",null=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='Title', unique=True,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Title
```

**views.py**

```
def blog_list(request):
    articles = Blogmodel.objects.all()
    args = {'articles':articles}
    return render(request,'blog.html',args)

def blogDetail(request, slug):
    article = Blogmodel.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    args = {'article':article}
    return render(request,'blogdetail.html',args)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import singCategory,Home,blog_list,blogDetail
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('',Home,name= "Home"),
    path('horoscope/<slug:slug>/<slug:cat>',singCategory,name='singCategory'),

    path("blog/",blog_list, name="blog_list"),
    path("blog/<slug:slug>",blogDetail, name="blogDetail"),  
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *settings.py*:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Your template:

```
<a href="/blog/{{ article.slug }}" class="blog_img"><img src="{{ article.image.url }}"></a>
```

Comment: I edit my html file please see. not working your solution

Answer (score 0):

check if you have Pillow installed, pip install pillow,